# OLE32 Exception when shutting down my Service

Tags: windows, com, ole

I have a Service application that crashes only on one PC (Windows XP) when shutting down via Services.

I get the following error on WinDbg:

```
(1038.728): Access violation - code c0000005 (!!! second chance !!!)
eax=00000000 ebx=00000000 ecx=0018b7a4 edx=77606e00 esi=0016b7f8 edi=0018b7a4
eip=7750cdbd esp=0012fe78 ebp=0012fe84 iopl=0         nv up ei pl nz na pe nc
cs=001b  ss=0023  ds=0023  es=0023  fs=003b  gs=0000             efl=00000202
...
ole32!StringFromCLSID+0x325
ole32!StringFromCLSID+0x2e7
ole32!StringFromCLSID+0x2c9
ole32!StringFromCLSID+0x215
ole32!StringFromCLSID+0x38f
RPCRT4!IUnknown_Release_Proxy+0x11
mfc100+0x20a229
MSVCR100!exit+0x11
```

My code uses a COM/Ole database control of some form and I access it like this:

```
CoInitializeEx( 0, COINIT_MULTITHREADED );

IClientTable    testCDS;
testCDS.CreateDispatch("ClientTableServer.ClientTable");
testCDS.ReleaseDispatch();

<Windows message loop>

CoUninitialize();
```

If I comment out the use of testCDS, there is no crash. I have tried combinations of ReleaseDispatch and DetachDispatch but I still get the same problem.

Help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: What's the type of `IClientTable`?

Comment: Sorry about the formatting below but I can't seem to edit it as code          class IClientTable : public COleDispatchDriver
{
public:
 IClientTable() {}  // Calls COleDispatchDriver default constructor
 IClientTable(LPDISPATCH pDispatch) : COleDispatchDriver(pDispatch) {}
 IClientTable(const IClientTable& dispatchSrc) : COleDispatchDriver(dispatchSrc) {}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm. This wasn't as tricky as I thought - there was another usage of IClientTable buried inside a library and ReleaseDispatch() wasn't being called. Problem solved.